# Is there any application of power law to predict large returns?

Tags: quant-trading-strategies

[Power law](http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~xgabaix/papers/powerLaws.pdf) basically states that after a certain threshold, probability distribution $p(x)\sim c\,x^{a}$ where $x > x_{min}$, which is often the case for financial time series.

It is also generally advised that estimation of parameter a is difficult as data in the tail is sparse. Can someone refer me to any application of power law in a trading context? E.g prediction of large returns, trading strategies, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You may have a look at what is called: econophysics. Basically, it applies techniques in statistical physics into financial time series, including power law as you mentioned. You may start with:

- This paper: [A theory of power-law distributions in financial market fluctuations](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwijor6-27HHAhUKHZQKHbsMDBE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpolymer.bu.edu%2Fhes%2Farticles%2Fggps03.pdf&ei=0qnSVaPxO4q60AS7mbCIAQ&usg=AFQjCNGHbhd72J6ucN8JOrGn6kUyrlbJ5g&bvm=bv.99804247,d.dGo)
- This classical book [Theory of Financial Risk and Derivative Pricing: From Statistical Physics to Risk Management](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521741866)
- A good start of econophysics:  [An introduction to econophysics](http://polymer.bu.edu/hes/book-mantegna00stanley.pdf).

I'm not expert in this field but hope it help.